# Changing cursor in browser not working

Tags: css

```
.squirell{
  position:absolute;
  cursor:  url("http://msunicorn.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Handyman_Hammer.ico");
 }
```

Other resources are successfully loading, is the size I'm using too big?

Comment: Try this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor/url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can change the cursor with a css only solution. see [here](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/cursor/).

```
cursor: url(images/my-cursor.png), auto;
```

Comment: i`m dont understund becouse its not working http://jsbin.com/vijir/6/watch?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 3):

**Used to this**

```
cursor:  [<url>,]* keyword
```

---

```
cursor:  url(http://www.example.com/bar.gif), auto;
```

**[more info cursor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor/url)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
cursor: url("http://msunicorn.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Handyman_Hammer.ico"), auto;
```

Is working for me.